# How to run a function contained in a R script, from Python ? The inputs for R function will be coming from Python

Tags: python, r, pycharm, forecasting

I am using Pycharm for Python. I have a script in R called 'forecast.R' which contains a function -> dummy_forecast(start_date, end_date) that outputs a 1 week ahead forecast on the given dates. The output is in a dataframe format containing time_stamp and forecast values. I want specify the input into the script from Python, and store the forecast dataframe in Python as well.

Is there any way to  import forecast.R script in python and call function dummy_forecast(), with inputs start_date and end_date stored in python and input into the function?

the rpy2 package is available. However, we need to write the entire R script  which is redundant and takes more processing time for the Python script.

I need this to be done in Pycharm not command line.

Answer (score 1):

If this 'R' script is written in python, you can edit the function to return the forecast at the end of its run, then when you call the function in the main script, you can assign a variable to it, so for instance:

Script R:

```
def dummy_forecast(s, e):
    #do calculations etc
    return forecast #or whatever you have called the data stored in here.
```

Main Script:

```
#as long as script R is in the same folder as the main script, you can just do:
import R
#if it is not, this is what you want to do:
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\directory\of\script\r')
import R

#then once you have imported R, you can do the following
start = 'blah blah'
end = 'blah blah'

forecast = R.dummy_forecast(start, end)
print forecast
```

Comment: It seems I haven't read your question properly, this won't be of any use for your problems, sorry! Good luck.

Comment: You can delete your answer then